# How to solve boat movements using Graph algorithm?

Tags: python, matrix, charts, depth-first-search

Appreciate your help to solve the following issue:

> A game grid represents water and land masses. The grid contains a True
> value where it's water and False where it's land.
> A boat can go to the next tile in the left or right directions, or move
> twice in the top and bottom directions. All the tiles in the path must be
> inside the grid and contain water.
> Implement the can_travel_to function, which accepts a grid matrix, starting
> and destination coordinates (row and column), and returns a boolean
> indicating whether a boat can travel between the two points in one step.
>
> For example, the following code:
>
> ```
> game matrix = [
>     [False, False, True, True, False],
>     [False, False, True, False, False],
>     [False, False, True, True, False],
>     [False, True, False, True, False],
>     [False, False, True, False, False]
> ]
>
> print(can_travel_to (game_matrix, 2, 2, 0, 2))
> print(can_travel_to (game_matrix, 2, 2, 2, 1))
> print(can_travel_to (game_matrix, 2, 2, 2, 3))
> print(can_travel_to(game_matrix, 2, 2, 4, 2))
>
> Should print:
>
> True
> False
> True
> False
> ```

I pass one case of tests but I can't with the other two which in case all coordinates inside the grid and some coordinates are outside the grid.

Check this link to test your solution [TestDome](https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/boat-movements/110076)

**Current solution**:

```py
class BoatMovements:
    def __init__(self, matrix, to_row, to_column):
        self.row = to_row
        self.column = to_column
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.visited = [
            [False for _ in range(len(matrix[0]))]
            for _ in range(len(matrix))
        ]

    def valid_move(self, row, column):

        if 0 <= row < len(self.matrix) and 0 <= column < len(self.matrix[0]):
            if self.matrix[row][column] and not self.visited[row][column]:
                return True

        return False

    def dfs_search(self, row, column):

        if not self.valid_move(row, column):
            return False

        if self.row == row and self.column == column:
            return True

        self.visited[row][column] = True

        return (self.dfs_search(row - 1, column) or
                self.dfs_search(row, column - 1) or
                self.dfs_search(row + 1, column) or
                self.dfs_search(row, column + 1))


def can_travel_to(game_matrix, from_row, from_column, to_row, to_column):

    try:
        # Check that:
        # 1- the given coordinates within the grid.
        # 2- the start and end coordinates is True.
        # 3- restrict the moves (two top/down and one left/right).
        if (to_row > len(game_matrix) - 1) or \
           (to_column > len(game_matrix) - 1) or \
           not game_matrix[from_row][from_column] or \
           not game_matrix[to_row][to_column] or \
           abs(to_row - from_row) > 2 or \
           abs(to_column - from_column) > 1:
            return False
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("The indexes must be valid indexes!")

    boat_movements = BoatMovements(game_matrix, to_row, to_column)
    return boat_movements.dfs_search(from_row, from_column)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the method `can_travel_to()` and the new update is:

```py
def can_travel_to(game_matrix, from_row, from_column, to_row, to_column):
    """Method to check if boatMovements instance is able to travel to given
    coordinates depending on starting point"""

    # Check that:
    # 1- The given coordinates within the grid.
    # 2- Restrict the steps (two when moving top/down and one left/right).
    if (to_row > len(game_matrix) - 1) or \
       (to_column > len(game_matrix[0]) - 1) or \
       (from_row != to_row and abs(to_row - from_row) != 2) or \
       (from_column != to_column and abs(to_column - from_column) != 1):

        return False

    # Check that The start and end coordinates are True, otherwise return False
    if not game_matrix[from_row][from_column] or \
       not game_matrix[to_row][to_column]:
        return False

    # Create a BoatMovements instance and set coordination of the end
    # destination.
    boat_movements = BoatMovements(game_matrix, to_row, to_column)

    # Call dfs method and return its response.
    return boat_movements.dfs_search(from_row, from_column)
```

**Note**: You can find the full code on [Github](https://github.com/Wadhah-Sky/Problems-Solving/blob/main/Python/boat_movements.py)